# Remove a slider from bxSlider on Next/Prev control click event

Tags: javascript, bxslider

I am facing a silly problem with bxSlider plugin. My slider only shows 4 slides with auto sliding mode. But when someone clicks on a particular nav link I am appending another slide relates to that link. But I wanted to remove that new slide when someone clicks on prev/next control and reload the default slider with 4 slides. But it's not working for that prev/next controls.

Here is the code:

```
//Default Slider
var slider= $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    displaySlideQty : 4,
    moveSlideQty : 4,
    maxSlides: 4,
    auto: true,
    autoStart: true,
    preloadImages: 'visible',
    mode: 'fade',
    pager: false,
});

//If someone clicks any link on navigation
$('#how').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  if( $('ul.bxslider li.added').length > 0 ){
    $('.bxslider').find('li.added').remove();
  }
  $('.bxslider').append('<li class="added"><a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Jwjv7OLazVY?enablejsapi=1&wmode=opaque" title="Click to Watch The Vieo"><img src="img/video.jpg"/></a></li>');
  slider.reloadSlider({
    mode:'fade',
    auto: false,
    autoStart: false,
    pager:false,

  });
  slider.goToSlide(4);

});
```

When the slide for #How tag is the current slide and then if I want to click any next/prev control I wanted to remove the slide 'li.added' and reload the default slider with 4 slides. That's I tried the following code

```
$('a.bx-next').click(function(e){
  if( $('ul.bxslider li.added').length > 0 ){
    $('.bxslider').find('li.added').remove();
    slider.reloadSlider({
    mode:'fade',
    auto: true,
    autoStart: true,
    pager:false,

  });
  }
});
```

but nothing happens! Can anyone please help me on this? What wrong I'm doing? Here is the [Live testing site](http://byevan.com/web-template/selleroutlet/) for you convenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that you need to bind the next button click function every time once you call reloadSlider, as it re-bind the next-previous control so it will lose the event binding if you do it at page load. So please rebind the click event every time you reload.

```
var bindNext = function(){

 $('a.bx-next').click(function(e){
  if( $('ul.bxslider li.added').length > 0 ){
    $('.bxslider').find('li.added').remove();
    slider.reloadSlider({
    mode:'fade',
    auto: true,
    autoStart: true,
    pager:false,

  });
  }
});
```

}

and then when you call reloadSlider then call the bindNext() function after calling it.

```
 $('#forSellers').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  if( $('ul.bxslider li.added').length > 0 ){
    $('.bxslider').find('li.added').remove();
  }

  $('.bxslider').append('<li class="added"><img src="img/seller.jpg" /></li>');
  slider.reloadSlider({

    auto: false,
    autoStart: false,
    pager:false,

    mode:'fade',
  });
  slider.goToSlide(4);

  bindNext();

});
```

Its working at my side.